# Understanding an implication involving operator norms:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't understand the following implication:

$$\|(I-E)^{-1}\| ≤ 1 + \|E\|\|(I-E)^{-1}\| \implies \|(I-E)^{-1}\| ≤ \dfrac{1}{1-\|E\|}$$

Comment: Where did you encounter this inequality?  Is your problem with finding the inequality in the first place, or is the problem with the implication?

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the inequality as follows:
$$
\|(I-E)^{-1}\| ≤ 1 + \|E\|\|(I-E)^{-1}\| \implies\\
\|(I-E)^{-1}\| - \|E\|\|(I-E)^{-1}\| \leq 1 \implies\\
(1 - \|E\|)\;\|(I-E)^{-1}\| \leq 1 \implies\\
\|(I-E)^{-1}\| \leq \frac 1{1 - \|E\|}
$$